# Why does setting an element's inner html to "" not clear the inner text?

Tags: javascript, html

Some friends and I are writing a game, and the inventory updates every time you open it. The inventory is separated into 16 boxes, and item names are written to these boxes. The function is supposed to clear the inventory before writing to it, but it doesn't clear.

```js
var assistInv = 0;
var invAssist = [];

//just some random items
var inventory = ['bottle', 'bottle', 'sword'];

function drawInventory() {
  //clears the inventory gui
  for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML = '';
  }

  //makes it easier to remove duplicate items for drawing
  inventory.sort();

  //inventory[0] cannot be a duplicate, and has no previous value to compare to
  invAssist.push(inventory[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    //this checks if the previous value is not the same as the current one
    if (inventory[i] != inventory[i - 1]) {
      invAssist.push(inventory[i]);
    }
  }

  //now the drawing part
  for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    //checks that the currently "selected" inventory space is open
    if (document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML == '') {
      //adds item to inventory gui
      document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML = invAssist[assistInv];

      //selects next item
      assistInv++;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    //inventory slots should outnumber inventory items
    if (document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML == 'undefined') {
      //clearing the element's innerHTML works here, but not at the top...
      document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML = '';
    }
  }

  assistInv = 0;
}
drawInventory();
```

```css
.invBoxes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#i1,
#i2,
#i3,
#i4,
#i5,
#i6,
#i7,
#i8 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 10px;
}

#i9,
#i10,
#i11,
#i12,
#i13,
#i14,
#i15,
#i16 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 10px;
}

#i2,
#i10 {
  left: 130px;
}

#i3,
#i11 {
  left: 250px;
}

#i4,
#i12 {
  left: 370px;
}

#i5,
#i13 {
  left: 490px;
}

#i6,
#i14 {
  left: 610px;
}

#i7,
#i15 {
  left: 730px;
}

#i8,
#i16 {
  left: 850px;
}
```

```html
<!--the inventory boxes-->
<div id="invBoxes">
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i1"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i2"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i3"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i4"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i5"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i6"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i7"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i8"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i9"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i10"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i11"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i12"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i13"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i14"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i15"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i16"></div>
</div>

<!--this adds items to the inventory for testing-->
<input id="add_to_inv">
<button onclick="inventory.push(document.getElementById('add_to_inv').value);drawInventory();">add item to inventory</button>
```

Comment: You don't initialize `assistInv` before you use it.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have fixed the sorting issue, but the inventory still doesn't clear when it redraws

Comment: You don't clear `invAssist` array, so at every call you just push new items after the ones already there. The easy fix is to move its declaration inside `drawInventory`

Comment: Not an answer, but a few tips. 1) Use `console.log()` to debug your code. And for more advanced cases research how to use chrome's dev tools on how to step through your code. 2) Comments shouldn't explain the how as much as they should explain why. The best code doesn't need comments. 3) and please oh please lookup css grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing `invAssist` between calls to `drawInventory()`. So each time you add an item to `inventory`, you append all the unique inventory items to the previous `invAssist` array.

`invAssist` doesn't need to be a global variable, you should create it locally to the function.

`assistInv` should also be local, and initialized to `0`.

```js
//just some random items
var inventory = ['bottle', 'bottle', 'sword'];

function drawInventory() {
  //clears the inventory gui
  for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML = '';
  }

  //makes it easier to remove duplicate items for drawing
  inventory.sort();

var assistInv = 0;
var invAssist = [];

  //inventory[0] cannot be a duplicate, and has no previous value to compare to
  invAssist.push(inventory[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    //this checks if the previous value is not the same as the current one
    if (inventory[i] != inventory[i - 1]) {
      invAssist.push(inventory[i]);
    }
  }

  //now the drawing part
  for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    //checks that the currently "selected" inventory space is open
    if (document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML == '') {
      //adds item to inventory gui
      document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML = invAssist[assistInv];

      //selects next item
      assistInv++;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    //inventory slots should outnumber inventory items
    if (document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML == 'undefined') {
      //clearing the element's innerHTML works here, but not at the top...
      document.getElementById('i' + i).innerHTML = '';
    }
  }
}
drawInventory();
```

```css
.invBoxes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#i1,
#i2,
#i3,
#i4,
#i5,
#i6,
#i7,
#i8 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 10px;
}

#i9,
#i10,
#i11,
#i12,
#i13,
#i14,
#i15,
#i16 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 10px;
}

#i2,
#i10 {
  left: 130px;
}

#i3,
#i11 {
  left: 250px;
}

#i4,
#i12 {
  left: 370px;
}

#i5,
#i13 {
  left: 490px;
}

#i6,
#i14 {
  left: 610px;
}

#i7,
#i15 {
  left: 730px;
}

#i8,
#i16 {
  left: 850px;
}
```

```html
<!--the inventory boxes-->
<div id="invBoxes">
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i1"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i2"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i3"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i4"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i5"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i6"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i7"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i8"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i9"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i10"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i11"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i12"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i13"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i14"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i15"></div>
  <div class="invBoxes" id="i16"></div>
</div>

<!--this adds items to the inventory for testing-->
<input id="add_to_inv">
<button onclick="inventory.push(document.getElementById('add_to_inv').value);drawInventory();">add item to inventory</button>
```